# How do I change Lubuntu's logout image?

Tags: lubuntu

How do I change Lubuntu's logout image?

[image: Lubuntu logout image...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image can be found here:

```
/usr/share/lubuntu/images/logout-banner.png
```

while the important labeling can be found here:

```
/usr/share/lubuntu/openbox/menu.xml
```

**Reference:**

- [Change word of "Logout Lubuntu Session"](http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=5294)