# Where is the LXDE logout menu?

Tags: menu, lxde

I'm looking for the LXDE logout menu and banner picture.

This useful question and answer [How do I change Lubuntu's logout image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725674/how-do-i-change-lubuntus-logout-image) is perfect for Lubuntu, but I am using LXDE over Ubuntu.

That answer gives `/usr/share/lubuntu/images/logout-banner.png` for the image. This was a useful clue to the LXDE location which is `/usr/share/lxde/images/logout-banner.png`.

That answer gives `/usr/share/lubuntu/openbox/menu.xml` for the menu, but sadly there's no corresponding `/usr/share/lxde/openbox/menu.xml` and searching my PC has proved fruitless.

Where is the logout `menu.xml` for LXDE (not Lubuntu)?

Comment: Did you look in `/etc/xdg/openbox`? There's `menu.xml`. You coul  copy it over to `~/.config/openbox` where you should already have `lxde-rc.xml` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks! I did find that one, but it's some other menu, not the logout one.  Same with `/etc/xdg/openbox/LXDE/menu.xml` (This one is the right-click desktop menu)

Comment: Do you have `/usr/share/applications/lxde-logout.desktop` listed as `Logout` when you open `/usr/share/applications` in PCManFM? Double-clicking `Logout` gives a window with various options: Shutdown, Reboot, Suspend, Switch User, Lock Screen, Logout, & Cancel. Above those options, there's an image and `Logout LXDE 18.04 session`? The image, `logout-banner.png`, is in `/usr/share/lxde/images`. I doubt there's an XML file that generates the listing I mentioned. I'm guessing it's part of the LXDE source code.

Comment: You might well be correct. I"m gonna look in a lubuntu install and verify how it works there.

Comment: After looking at a Lubuntu install, the answer to the question I quoted above appears to be incorrect when it states the location of the exit menu.  So @DKBose I think you are right and if you want to put it in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44083159/lxde-change-text-in-logout-session/64413152#64413152) in stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the 18.04 Ubuntu minimal CD (iso) in a virtual machine and chose `Lubuntu Minimal` as the desktop since an `LXDE` option was not specifically available.

In this system, the image for the logout banner that one sees (boxed in red) in the image below is `/usr/share/lxde/images/logout-banner.png`.

[image: Logout banner image]

As for the list of options below the banner, my guess is that it is part of the LXDE source code and not something meant to be normally available to the end-user for modifying by way of an `xml` file.

One can look at `/usr/share/applications/lxde-logout.desktop` listed as "Logout" when you open `/usr/share/applications` in PCManFM to find the executable that generates the logout screen.

```
Exec=lxde-logout
TryExec=lxsession-logout
```

---

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1011884/248158) also addresses the issue and concludes that

> ... after reading and researching more it does not look like it is possible to edit the logout session options without editing and recompiling the source code.